# How to fetch record to session or querystring in php

Tags: php

I want to fetch the userid from my php code for this I create a class for fetch record this is my code

My database Manager Class

```
public function executeQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result === false) {
            $this->closeConnection($this->conn);
            exit;
        }
            // extract data from results, returning an associative array
            $rows = Array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {         
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
            return $rows;
    }
```

Class for Fetch records

```
function checkLogin($arr)
    {
        require_once(FRONT_ROOT_PATH.'DatabaseManager.php');
        $query ="Select * from tbusers where username='".$arr['username']."'and
           password='".$arr['password']."'";
        $db= new DatabaseManager();
        $result=$db->executeQuery($query);
        return $result;
    }
```

and this function i am calling here

```
if(isset($_POST['addlogin']))
    {
        $obj= new LoginManager();
        $userlist=$obj->checkLogin($_POST);
    if(Count($userlist)>0)
    {

        header('location:/ProjectDream/view/home/home.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Login Failed";
    }
```

Now from here I want to add userid in session 
Please tell me how can i do it?

Comment: did you used session for this ? is yes then simply use echo $_SESSION['your_session_id']

Comment: yeah my question is this how can i fetch id from my database to session @SagarPanchal

Answer (score 0):

first session on the start of the code and replace this your code

```
if(Count($userlist)>0)
    {
        $userlist['id']=$_SESSION['your_var_name']; //setting your userid to session var
        header('location:/ProjectDream/view/home/home.php');
    }
```

Comment: when i go to home.php its show me blank page
i write this code on my home.php
<?php
 session_start();
 $userid=$_SESSION['uid'];
 echo  $userid;
?>

Comment: @AzadChouhan lets discuss on chat bro. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46799/amdavadi-developers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start();
if(Count($userlist)>0)
{
   $_SESSION['username']=$userlist['username'];
   header('location:/ProjectDream/view/home/home.php');
}
else 
{
  echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You can fetch particular record from $userlist array and store it in session variable.
<?php
if(Count($userlist)>0)
{
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['username']=$userlist['username'];
   header('location:/ProjectDream/view/home/home.php');
}
else 
{
    echo "Login Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: getting this error
Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\ProjectDream\View\Home\Home.php on line 3